# How to deserialize a map with a List of complex objects in Jackson?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I got a special usecase where I need to deserialize something very complex.

```
Map<String, List<SharepointFile>> areaMappings =
    (Map<String, List<SharepointFile>>) execution.getVariable("areaMappings");
```

Don't worry about `execution.getVariable("areaMappings")` it just returns the valuue of the saved variable (it's Camunda). `SharepointFile` is a complex object here. It only contains simple types like String, boolean etc. Still Jackson is not able to convert it.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser (java.util.ArrayList is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser is in unnamed module of loader org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader @17a7cec2)
```

I can save it without problems and also retrieve it in the frontend but if I want to use it again in Java the deserialization crashes.

We have customized the JacksonMapper with additional modules and also this:

```
    .setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    .enable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_ENUMS_USING_TO_STRING)
    .enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_ARRAY_AS_NULL_OBJECT)
    .disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)
    .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false));
```

How can I fix this?

Edit: `SharepointFile`:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class SharepointFile implements Serializable {
  private String fileName;
  private String filePath;
  private String downloadLink;
  private LocalDateTime localDateTime;
  private String userName;
  private String type;
  private Boolean selected;

  public SharepointFile(
      String fileName,
      String filePath,
      String downloadLink,
      LocalDateTime localDateTime,
      String userName,
      String type) {
    this.fileName = fileName;
    this.filePath = filePath;
    this.downloadLink = downloadLink;
    this.localDateTime = localDateTime;
    this.userName = userName;
    this.type = type;
    this.selected = false;
  }
}
```

Edit: I was looking at the wrong point. This one is crashing:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

  List<SharepointFile> sharepointFileList =
      mapper.readValue((JsonParser) entry.getValue(), new TypeReference<>() {});
```

Comment: Please share your deserialization code as well as `SharepointFile` class

Comment: Deserialization code? There is no. It is the default Jackson Mapper.

Comment: What is `entry` in the last code sample?